# How to get values of <input type="checkbox" /> that are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

There are multiple `<input type="checkbox" value="..." />` in the page.

I need to get each of the `<input>` that is checked to do some operation.

I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each ( function() {
   alert ( $(this).val() );
});
```

or you can use

```
$("input:checkbox")
```

selector

If all the checkboxes are inside a container then you can narrow the selector by using

```
$("#containerID input[type=checkbox]:checked" )
```

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.9+ `$(this).va()` is unreliable for value properties and you should use `$(this).prop("value")` instead. or `$(this).is(":checked");`

Comment: here how to get checkboxes having class="ig"?

Comment: $('select').each(function () {
            //do something
        });
here how to get all selects having class=ip

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this:

```
$(":checkbox :checked").each(function(){
  alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: From jQuery docs; $(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('*:checkbox') which is a slow selector. It's recommended to do $('input:checkbox').

Comment: Your selector is wrong. It selects all checked elements **inside** checkboxes… which is… *impossible*.