# How to select unchecked input type checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, unchecked

I have some a table in which i have rows with same id and other rows with other same id.
Every row has a checkbox and i want to change the backgroundcolor of all the unchecked checkbox inside all rows with one id. this is what i try to do:

```
function resetOtherCheckBox(){
   $('#sent').find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').css('background-color', '#33CCCC');
}
```

what is the error? help me pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get values of <input type="checkbox" /> that are checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806882/how-to-get-values-of-input-type-checkbox-that-are-checked)

Comment: i would assume that `resetOtherCheckBox` is never called.

Comment: You just cannot have multiple times the same ID - this will lead to unexpected results. Change this to use a class or a data- attribute.

Comment: i call it in another function :var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");  
    var nbChecked = checked.size(); 
    if(nbChecked==1){
       $('tr[name="' + checked.attr('name') + '"]').css('background-color', '#ffff33');
       resetOtherCheckBox();..........

Comment: alternatively, `#sent` might not be a parent of the checkboxes. You'll have to post more code if you want more help beyond speculation.

Comment: @DidierGhys no way :( it doesn't work with class.. i change in $("tr.sent")....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve in this way:

```
$("tr.sent input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parents('tr').css('background-color', '#33CCCC');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sent').find('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KWSr/1/